# creating proper json string to store in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I wanted to create a string which can be stored in localstorage,so that i can add,delete later.
I wanted to create my json string in this format.

```
var frmTaxYear = [{
"CategoryDisplayText": abc,
  "CategoryId": 1,
  "taxyear": {
    "taxYearId": 1,
    "taxYearDisplayText": abc
  }
}]
[{
  "CategoryDisplayText": abc2,
  "CategoryId": 2,
  "taxyear": {
    "taxYearId": 2,
    "taxYearDisplayText": abc1
  }
}]
```

The code which I have been written is

```
function addToCart() {
  var taxyearObj = [];
  $('[name="Taxyear"]:checked').map(function() {
    taxyearObj.push({
      "taxYearId": this.value,
      "taxYearDisplayText": $('label[id=' + this.id + ']').text()
    });

  });
  if (localStorage.getItem("taxyear") !== null) {

    //  findAndRemove(localStorage.getItem("taxyear"), 'CategoryId', CategoryId.val());
    var frmTaxYear = [{
      "CategoryDisplayText": CategoryDisplayText.text(),
      "CategoryId": CategoryId.val(),
      "taxyear": taxyearObj
    }];
    var storedTaxyear = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("taxyear"));
    storedTaxyear.push(frmTaxYear);
    localStorage.setItem("taxyear", JSON.stringify(storedTaxyear));
  } else {
    var frmTaxYear = [{
      "CategoryDisplayText": CategoryDisplayText.text(),
      "CategoryId": CategoryId.val(),
      "taxyear": taxyearObj
    }];
    localStorage.setItem('taxyear', JSON.stringify(frmTaxYear));
  }
}
```

But the problem is the when user click on add to cart first time ,it is stored in local storage as object and when user click on add to cart again second list is stored as array

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing an array onto an array. One way to avoid this is to initialize the `taxyear` to `[]` if it's null and to always push an object. Then you don't have to define `frmTaxYear` twice:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("taxyear") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("taxyear", JSON.stringify([]));
} 

var frmTaxYear = {
    "CategoryDisplayText": CategoryDisplayText.text(),
    "CategoryId": CategoryId.val(),
    "taxyear": taxyearObj
};

var storedTaxyear = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("taxyear"));
storedTaxyear.push(frmTaxYear);
localStorage.setItem("taxyear", JSON.stringify(storedTaxyear));
```

Comment: not working ,var frmTaxYear = {
    "CategoryDisplayText": CategoryDisplayText.text(),
    "CategoryId": CategoryId.val(),
    "taxyear": taxyearObj
};

Comment: taxyearObj will be generated in foreach loop.

Comment: @user1681166 yes the code that generates `taxyearObj` should stay the same. this answer replaces your `if` statement

Comment: getting error : at line storedTaxyear.push(frmTaxYear);                   Uncaught TypeError: storedTaxyear.push is not a function

Comment: @user1681166 see update. you may need to reset your localStorage